# Creating a C++ macro that allows for easy creation of virtual-function wrapper functions

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am writing a modification for an old game and am utilizing basic reverse engineering to achieve my goal. Essentially I have been recreating simple versions of reverse engineered game structs and interfaces in my own code, building my solution as a shared object and loading it in the game.

My current solution to keeping the code simple is to only include the functions I need in "my versions" of the reverse engineered interfaces, and to do that I simply write something like:

```cpp
class GameManager {
public:
    Game* GetGame();
    Game* NextGame();
    Game* PreviousGame();
    int   GameCount();
...
};
```

and then implement the functions as simple wrappers that call the original functions by index in the virtual method table. This way I can only include what I need, etc etc.

Each of these consists of essentially `SomeType* SomeFunction(int param){ typedef thiscall blabla; call_vfunc(1,this,param); }`

I want to write a macro that automates this process, something simple and easy use like `#define VFUNC(index, returnType, name, parameters)`.

I messed around with it and made a few failed attempts at achieving this. The most recent one looks like so:

```cpp
#define VFUNC(index, returnType, name, ...) returnType name(__VA_ARGS__) { return call_vfunc(index, this, ##__VA_ARGS__); }
```

This works when the function doesn't take any parameters but the problem is that once I introduce parameters (for exaxmple, writing `VFUNC(12, int, someFunction, int someParam)` I end up passing the whole declaration when I only want to pass the names of the parameters. I've been thinking of a way I can turn (int a, int b, int c) into (a,b,c) so I can just pass them in to call_vfunc but so far I have nothing.

**TLDR:** I'm wanting to write a macro that automates the process of creating these virtual-function "wrapper functions".

Thank you. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated =)
I'll keep you updated if I figure it out.

Comment: "I want to write a macro" - Stop right there and reconsider. Macros are *evil*. You don't want to use them except as a last resort when they are the *only* option left.

Comment: Usually you'd use Boost.Preprocessor for this kind of fancy macros.

Comment: Thank you for the super quick responses. These functions are super boring and  and I agree with avoiding macros at all costs. They're just super repetitive and I feel like writing the same thing 400 times is a little pointless.

These classes often consist of tens of functions that I need to use so I end up with 4 lines of code per function times ten or more usually so I think the use of macros to shorten these is justified. I will look at Boost.Preprocessor, thank you!

Comment: You can write easily if you can have a max number of parameter by providing a conversion from `__VA_ARGS__` to another macro with fixed number of arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your macro.

Usage:

```
VFUNC(1, int, foo)
VFUNC_P(1, int, foo, (int,x))
VFUNC_P(1, int, foo, (int,x), (float,y))
```

Implementation:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#define VA_COUNT(...) VA_COUNT_(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
#define VA_COUNT_(p5, p4, p3, p2, p1, x, ...) x

#define FOR_EACH(macro, ...) CAT(FOR_EACH_, VA_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__))(macro, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_1(m, p1                ) m p1
#define FOR_EACH_2(m, p1, p2            ) m p1 , m p2
#define FOR_EACH_3(m, p1, p2, p3        ) m p1 , m p2 , m p3
#define FOR_EACH_4(m, p1, p2, p3, p4    ) m p1 , m p2 , m p3 , m p4
#define FOR_EACH_5(m, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) m p1 , m p2 , m p3 , m p4 , m p5

#define VFUNC_param_decl(type_, name_) ::std::enable_if_t<1, type_> name_
#define VFUNC_param_use(type_, name_) name_

#define VFUNC(index_, return_type_, name_) \
    return_type_ name_() \
    { return call_vfunc(index_, this); }

#define VFUNC_P(index_, return_type_, name_, ...) \
    return_type_ name_( FOR_EACH(VFUNC_param_decl, __VA_ARGS__) ) \
    { return call_vfunc(index_, this, FOR_EACH(VFUNC_param_use, __VA_ARGS__)); }
```

The simple implementation provided above has a few limitations:

- There is a separate macro for functions with 0 parameters.
- You need to prepare `O(n)` boilerplate macros, where `n` is the maximum amount of function parameters you want to support. The code above supports up to 5 parameters.

There is a way to fix both of those problems, but it would require even more ugly macros. It doesn't seem to be worth it.

---

You could rewrite those macros to use Boost.Preprocessor library. (Use `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ` + `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` or something similar.)

It would allow you to get rid of the boilerplate (because it would be provided by the library).

Comment: Works great on g++ but the macro expands a little weird with more than one parameter in MSVC (second parameter ends up as just (int, something) instead of ::std::enable_if_t<type_> name_. Thank you so much for all your help :)